# matplotlib & LaTeX - ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pdflatex

I'm having a hard time using LaTeX with matplotlib.

I was able to reduce the error to this.

MWE

```
# %%  LaTeX


import matplotlib as mpl

pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "font.family": "serif",
    "pgf.preamble": "\n".join([           # plots will use this preamble
        r"\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
        ])
    }

mpl.use('pgf')  # To use \siunitx
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)


# %%  Import Data

import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\marco\Desktop")


import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)
Y = np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)

# XList = [   np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360),     np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)]
# YList = [1* np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360), 2 * np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)]


# %%  Plotting


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,
                       figsize=(6, 4),
                       dpi=500
                      )

ColorList = ["blue", "red"]

for i in range(2):

    ax.plot(X,
            (i+1) * Y,
            label= f"i",
            color= ColorList[i]
            )

for i in range(len(XList)):

    ax.scatter(XList[i],
               YList[i] * 1000,
               color = ColorList[i]
               )


fig.savefig("Plot.png")
```

MNWE

```
# %%  LaTeX


import matplotlib as mpl

pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "font.family": "serif",
    "pgf.preamble": "\n".join([           # plots will use this preamble
        r"\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
        ])
    }

mpl.use('pgf')  # To use \siunitx
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)


# %%  Import Data

import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\marco\Desktop")


import numpy as np
# X = np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)
# Y = np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)

XList = [   np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360),     np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)]
YList = [1* np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360), 2 * np.linspace(1, 5000, 3360)]


# %%  Plotting


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,
                       figsize=(6, 4),
                       dpi=500
                      )

ColorList = ["blue", "red"]

# for i in range(2):

#     ax.plot(X,
#             np.log(X) * (i+1),
#             label= f"i",
#             color= ColorList[i]
#             )

for i in range(len(XList)):

    ax.scatter(XList[i],
               YList[i] * 1000,
               color = ColorList[i]
               )

fig.savefig("PlotMNEW.png")
```

The last one gives

```
RuntimeError: The command
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error figure.tex
failed and generated the following output:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.7.26) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(figure.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-07-15>
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty)

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' is turned off
(hyperref)                because \thepage is undefined.

) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex-dev/graphics\mathcolor.ltx))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.co
de.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)

(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.
tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmeti
cs.code.tex)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.t
ex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.te
x)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code
.tex) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.
tex) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.te
x) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
 (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file figure.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (figure.pgf
Runaway text?
q 0.0 -3.0004 m 0.79541 -3.0004 1.55898 -2.68398 2.12148 -2.12148 c 2\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
<argument> ...8 c 1.55898 2.68398 0.79541 3.0004 0
                                                  .0 3.0004 c -0.79541 3.000...
l.20610 \pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}
                                          %
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on figure.log.

and the following error:
```

I can't make any sense of it.

- I can also chose an arbitrarily large number for the linspace on the MWE and it works.
- It is solved by using luatex instead of pdflatex. However, that leads to complications on the real code (such as not recongnising fonts).
- At some point, I was able to run some version of the second code with with LaTex without errors.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error and found a solution, which may not be the best, but helped me.

As I understand, the amount of data you want to plot in a figure is too large. That means allocated memory in the amount of *3000000* is too small, so the process is aborted. The following error message appears in the report:

***! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].***

You can increase this as follows.

> 1. open a command window (Windows key and type "cmd") or the PowerShell (Windows key and type "Windows PowerShell").
> 2. at the shell, enter
>
> *initexmf --edit-config-file=latex*
>
> 3. add the following line into the open editor (Be careful with the chosen memory size).
>
> *main_memory=12000000*
>
> to the file, save it and quit the editor.
>
> 4. to rebuild the format, enter
>
> *initexmf --dump=latex*
>
> 5. repeat steps 2-4 with configuration files *pdflatex* and *xelatex*. Also you might want to repeat it with *lualatex*.

For more information go to the page [Increase LaTeX memory](https://florian-rappl.de/Articles/Page/239/latex-memory).

For the script *MNWE* I get the following figure.

[image: Figure MNWE]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I wasn't able to respond before. Lately I haven't been facing the errors (although, it is probably only due to the particulars datasets I've been working on) and I doubt I will encounter it in the near future. However, I will be using TikZ more frequently and, therefore, I appreciate the reference you provided as it may prove useful. If the time comes, I'll comment on it.

Comment: The `lualatex` method works the best for me.